# How to swipe WebViews in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, webview, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin Android. I am trying to implement a program which swipes several WebViews by sliding the fingers through a ribbon at the bottom of the WebView. So far, I have written the following code in the main activity:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace WebSwipe
{
    [Activity(Label = "WebSwipe", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        private WebView _webview;
        private ImageView touchband;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            _webview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
            touchband = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            _webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            _webview.LoadUrl("http://www.gnu.org");
            touchband.Touch += OnTouch;
        }

        private void OnTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs touchEventArgs)
        {
            string[] pages = new string[] {
            "http://www.computerchess.org.uk",
            "http://gcc.gnu.org",
            "http://es.wikipedia.org"
                             };

            for (int count = 0; count < 3; ++count) 
            {
                switch (touchEventArgs.Event.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask) 
                {
                    case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    case MotionEventActions.Up:
                        _webview.LoadUrl (pages [count]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this code doesn't work, because by swiping the first page "http://www.gnu.org"," I am sent to last page "http://es.wikipedia.org", without passing through the intermediate pages. I still cannot figure out how to achieve this; excuse me my ignorance, but I come from a C++ background and I am barely learning C#. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You load all 3 pages on every touch so the last is always visible after the touch

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace WebSwipe
{
    [Activity(Label = "WebSwipe", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        private WebView _webview;
        private ImageView touchband;

        string[] pages;
        int currentPage = 0;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            pages = new string[] {
                "http://www.gnu.org"
                "http://www.computerchess.org.uk",
                "http://gcc.gnu.org",
                "http://es.wikipedia.org"
                 };

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            _webview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
            touchband = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            _webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            _webview.LoadUrl(pages[currentPage]);
            touchband.Touch += OnTouch; 
        }

        private void OnTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs touchEventArgs)
        {

            for (int count = 0; count < 3; ++count) 
            {
                switch (touchEventArgs.Event.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask) 
                {
                    case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    case MotionEventActions.Up:
                        currentPage++;
                        if (currentPage >= pages.Count) currentPage = 0;

                        _webview.LoadUrl (pages [currentPage]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the code, but this one didn't work for me. While I did some modifications for it worked, it continued to have the same behavior as mine. I didn't understand the array member Count; I assumed that it was the variable count.